# Is there offline Kanji handwriting software for PC?

Tags: discussion, kanji

I love the way of handwriting dictionary, especially for Kanji. Traditional way is very time consuming. This site provide good solution for my way. But I need Internet to run it

> http://kanji.sljfaq.org/

Is there a offline solution for handwriting lookup Kanji dictionary?

Answer (score 0):

[gwaei](http://sourceforge.net/projects/gwaei/) is a free open-source software that matches your description. It's being developed for Linux/Unix (latest version 3.6.2), but [there is also a Windows installer for version 3.6.1](http://sourceforge.net/projects/gwaei/files/gwaei/3.6.x/). (It uses kanjipad for kanji handwriting recognition.)

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need a special software to draw a kanji character and select it from a suggestion list on a PC, although you might have to add a component of the operating system beforehand. [Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oNhWqkIshaI) is an example for Windows.

You might also consider using [Google Japanese Input](https://www.google.co.jp/intl/ja/ime/) for either Windows or Mac. It also has handwriting recognition.